# Program to identify number should be in increments of 1000

Tags: .net, vb.net

In VB.NET, We have one text field and we are taking decimal number as input.

**Example:** Input number is 7000.01 and we are dividing it by 1000. We want input
number should be in increments of 1000.

**Code snippet:**

vAnswersErrs(MINADDINDEX) is input number.

```
If CLng(vAnswers(MINADDINDEX) Mod 1000) = 0 Then
     fDldErrors = True
     vAnswersErrs(MINADDINDEX) = "Minimum amount must be in increments of 1000"
End If
If Int(CLng(vAnswers(MINADDINDEX)) / 1000) <> (CLng(vAnswers(MINADDINDEX)) / 1000) Then
     fDldErrors = True
     vAnswersErrs(MINADDINDEX) = "Maximum amount must be in increments of 1000"
End If
```

Currently it is allowing decimal points, but it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `CLng` you will not be able to detect decimals. Use `CDec` instead. `CDec` returns the number as `Decimal`. This is better than `Double` in this context, as `Double` tends to produce conversion errors. E.g., `CDbl("7000")` could be returned as 6999.9999...

```vb
Dim answer As Decimal = CDec("7000.1")
If answer Mod 1000 = 0 Then
    ...
End If
```

I don't know what the type of `vAnswersErrs` is, but if it is an `Integer` or `Long`, this will not work. If it is a `String`, then `CDec(vAnswers(MINADDINDEX)) Mod 1000 = 0` will work.